# Locating Moon in Sky from Earth

Tags: latitude-longitude, algorithm, time, gis-principle, moon

I am working on project which need to find moon location from a specified lat, long on earth. So basically info I am having is Lat,Long and Timezone.

**Format of the moon location Info?**
So first in which values its possible to get moon location? eg lat, long of moon with some angle from origin point or may be something else.

**How do I get this info?**
Now how I can get moon location in possible formats?

I have only basic knowledge of GIS and I haven't worked on project which includes outside planet. So a brief about Positioning system used to locate plants or sun would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

A simple search with Google threw up this website...

http://jgiesen.de/elevazmoon/basics/index.htm

Comment: and this one as well http://www.stjarnhimlen.se/comp/ppcomp.html and for the parameters -   http://www.satellite-calculations.com/Satellite/suncalc.htm

Comment: Can you provide a pseudo code?